# comparing two columns if one column value is in text and other is a radio button in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how to compare two columns if one column value is in text (OK/NG)and the other is a radio button(Manual Eval) and output result in the third column(Difference) in HTML? I need to compare two columns and post the result in third column using jquery or javascript, Im new to html and stackoverflow , please ignore my coding style for now , it will improve with time and practice

Image of my table added for your reference

[data table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx8De.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
      

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li
                        role="presentation" class="active"><a 
                        href="/">Home</a>
                        
                    </li>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h2> Table </h2>
        </div>
    </div>

<h2><center>TABLE</center></h2>
<div id="content"  >

 <table id="tbl" class="sortable" align="center" >
  <tr>
    <th><center>No.</center></th>
    <th><center>OK/NG</center></th>
    <th><center>Manual Eval</center></th>
      <th><center>Difference</center></th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
     <tr>

    <td></td>
    <td>OK</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
    </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
    <td name ="diff"> </td>
     </tr>

  <tr>

    <td></td>

    <td>OK</td>

      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
    </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
    <td name ="diff"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td></td>

    <td>OK</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
    </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
    <td name ="diff"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>OK</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
    </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
    <td name ="diff"> </td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>NG</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
    </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
    <td name ="diff"> </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

 </table>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: what's your question, its not clear. What exactly do you want ?

Comment: the column 2 (OK/NG) has values in text and column 3(Manual Eval) has radio button, if the col2 has OK and col3 has NG selected by user there should be automatic text "checked in col4(difference), if both col2 and col3 has same values then there should be blank in col4

Comment: `name` of radio button should be different per rows . Also , what you have tried to achieve above ?

Comment: solution to my problem is close to this https://jsbin.com/equwi6/2/edit?html,js,output, but in my case its radio button

Comment: @Swati, please check above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it my self, for anyone who wants the solution[image: image for reference]

```js
function checkDiff(){
  var radioArr =[]
  var radio = document.getElementsByClassName('selection');
  var predict = document.getElementsByClassName('pred');
  var difference = document.getElementsByClassName('diff');
  //console.log(predict.length);
  for( var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++ ){
    if(radio[i].name="selection") {
      //console.log(radio[i].value,i);
      if(radio[i].checked){
        radioArr.push(radio[i].value)
      }
    }
  }
  //console.log(radioArr)

  for( var i = 0; i < radioArr.length; i++ ) {
    if(radioArr[i] !== predict[i].innerHTML) {
        console.log(i,predict[i].innerHTML,radioArr[i]);
        difference[i].innerHTML ="&#10003"
    } els e{
      difference[i].innerHTML ="same"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li
                role="presentation" class="active"><a 
                href="/">Home</a>
                
            </li>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h2> Table </h2>
  </div>
</div>

<h2><center>TABLE</center></h2>
<div id="content">

 <table id="tbl" class="sortable" align="center" >
  <tr>
    <th><center>No.</center></th>
    <th><center>OK/NG</center></th>
    <th><center>Manual Eval</center></th>
      <th><center>Difference</center></th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
          <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
      </td>
          <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
      <td name ="diff"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
        <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
      </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
      <td name ="diff"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
          <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
      </td>
          <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
      <td name ="diff"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
          <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
      </td>
          <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
      <td name ="diff"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>NG</td>
      <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ok" > OK
          <input type="radio" name = "selection" value="ng"> NG </br>
      </td>
          <input type="hidden" name="selection"  />
      <td name ="diff"> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```